# c++20 views with parameter pack or initialiser list

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I want to take a variable amount of arguments to a function and then get a view to them. I need to apply multiple functions to each one. I have been trying to get this to work with both parameter packs and initialiser lists. How come these solutions don't work and is there any way to do this?

Ideally the final function will look like so:

```cpp
template <typename some_way_of_taking_multiple_arguments>
void foo(some_way_of_taking_multiple_arguments bar) {
  using namespace std::views;
  auto data = bar | transform(func1) | transform(func2);
  other_func();
  data | transform(func3);
}
```

When I try to call the function like so: foo({arg1, arg2, arg3}), it cannot deduce the template type.

Comment: You should add the versions you tried, and the errors you get for each one.

Comment: It's proprietary code so can only share the pattern without going into type definitions and the such

Comment: I'm sure you can make a [mre] with just a couple of lines that demonstrates the problem. Besides, asking for help with proprietary code is frowned upon at SO.

Comment: I'm now sure the reason this wasn't working is because func 3 had a return type of void. This is illustrated here: https://godbolt.org/z/8zara4

Comment: @cigien Where is it frowned upon?  It is frowned upon to not provide enough information to answer, which can get in the way if you have proprietary code; that just means more work for the OP.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Fair enough, I don't know if it's frowned upon, it just annoys me :( I should delete that part of the comment I guess, but I want to keep the part about the MRE.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One way I've found to do this is to set the paramater type to std::initializer_list and then change the line:

`data | transform(func3);`
to:
`for (const auto &datum: data) {func3(datum);}`

This is because the return type of func3 is void, you can only use std::views::transform with functions which return something.

Demo [here](https://godbolt.org/z/8zara4)

Answer (score 4):

So long as all the arguments are of the same type, you can construct an `initializer_list` like this:

```
void foo(auto ... bar_args) 
{
  using namespace std::views;

  std::initializer_list bar{bar_args...};  // uses CTAD to deduce type

  auto data = bar | transform(func1) | transform(func2);
  data | transform(func3);
}
```

and invoke it like this:

```
int main()
{
  int a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4;
  foo(a,b,c,d); 
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/xrvf16).

Comment: I guess using an std::array should be better, no?

Comment: @AntoineMorrier Actually, an `array` will copy the underlying elements, whereas `initializer_list` is more lightweight, and is closer to a `view`. An array would be fine too.

Comment: I didn't know that initializer_list is more lightweight. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

```
template<class T, std::size_t N>
void foo( T const(& arg)[N] ) {
  for( auto x : arg )
    std::cout << x;
}
```

This can be called like:

```
foo( {1,2,3} );
```

an array works with [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) views fine.